# Totaling scores in C++

Tags: c++

Okay so I when I run this code I get that my total is equal to 0 and that
messes up my average and grade.I am not sure what I am doing wrong as the
total += scores function is where it should be, yet it is still not adding up
the scores.

```
int validateNumber(int, int, int);
```

in `main()` function

```
int num, score, total = 0;
```

and

```
validateNumber(num, score, total);
```

and the definition

```
int validateNumber(int num, int score, int total) {
  while (num < 1 || num > 4) {
    cout << over3 << num << " is not between 1 and 4! Try again: ";
    cin >> num;
  }
  system("CLS");
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    cout << over3 << "Enter score " << i << ": " << endl;
    cout << over3 << "Enter a value from 0 to 100: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (score < 0 || score > 100) {
      cout << over3 << score
           << " is not between 0 and 100! Renter the score: " << i << ": ";
      cin >> score;
    }
    total += score;
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile due to not all variables being defined, missing includes and `main`. I am not sure you will receive relevant help with this. It would also be great if you could briefly explain what you expect this code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement the `validate()` function like you did here,

```
validateNumber(num,score,total);
```

you can make it `void` and pass the variable `total` as reference. e.g,

```
void validateNumber(int num, int score, int &total) {
  while (num < 1 || num > 4) {
    cout << over3 << num << " is not between 1 and 4! Try again: ";
    cin >> num;
  }
  system("CLS");
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    cout << over3 << "Enter score " << i << ": " << endl;
    cout << over3 << "Enter a value from 0 to 100: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (score < 0 || score > 100) {
      cout << over3 << score
           << " is not between 0 and 100! Renter the score: " << i << ": ";
      cin >> score;
    }
    total += score;
  }
}
```

and the rest would be same...
Otherwise I wouldn't have use 3 arguments in this case. e.g,

```
int validateNumber(int num) {
  int total=0,score;
  while (num < 1 || num > 4) {
    cout << over3 << num << " is not between 1 and 4! Try again: ";
    cin >> num;
  }
  system("CLS");
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    cout << over3 << "Enter score " << i << ": " << endl;
    cout << over3 << "Enter a value from 0 to 100: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (score < 0 || score > 100) {
      cout << over3 << score
           << " is not between 0 and 100! Renter the score: " << i << ": ";
      cin >> score;
    }
    total += score;
  }
  return total;
}
```

and the call:

```
int num, total;
...
total=validateNumber(num);
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: awesome! thank you very much! I'm still not exactly sure why total = validateNumber()

Comment: If `num` is to be changed inside the function, it should either be returned or passed by reference.

Comment: Read about `local variables` from book.. Here if it's not passed as reference then the `total` used in `main()` and the `total` in that function is totally different variable... :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming the function call `validateNumber(num,score,total);` in line 5 would calculate the total? You should call the function from `main` function, and assign the return value to a variable, (e.g. `total`).

Comment: Why is total not a variable though? I'm not sure how I would declare it ion the main any better... do I need to put the for...loop in the main?